# clickable flow control bread crumb vs next / prev button

Tags: breadcrumbs, click, task-flow

I have a checkout flow - breadcrumb UI component at the top of my page that looks like this.

[image]

The labels are different from what have been shown.

A form is associated with each step in the flow. It has to be completed , But the user now will also be able to see the second form without filling the first. ( kind of sneak peak )

As of now my breadcrumbs are clickable and any form can be seen independently.

Is this a good UX ?

If no - What other possibilities are there for the user to get an idea of how much he has to fill in ?

If yes - Is making the breadcrumb clickable a good idea when compared to a prev/next button ?

Comment: This may look like a breadcrumb, but it isn't. A breadcrumb reveals the current path within a hierarchy; whereas yours is a step menu.

Comment: Which real problem you are trying to solve with that approach? Breadcrumbs aren't a good mean to support sequential flow. The Wizard pattern does.

Comment: This is a wizard and used when there is a procedure involved for filling up the information. There are 2 types of wizards 1) non-modal 2) sequential. In non-modal, a user can jump among any step, but in sequential it is not possible. Without completing the first step, user is not allowed to go to 2nd step.

Comment: Thanks for the term step menu , I was always confused what to call it.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue **no**, this is not good UX. For the following reasons:

- Why would a user checkout after getting an order confirmation? Typically, order confirmations are the very last step in online transactions, with order numbers, shipping information, etc.
- Why would a user want to "preview" checkout before browsing?
- In your current UI, you define a progression between steps, signifying that one needs to be completed before the other. Even if there is a functional reason for my second question, this wouldn't be apparent to the user in the current interface.

Let me know if you have any clarifying details so I can modify my answer.

P.S. I agree with Izhaki, your progress bar is not breadcrumbs UI. Breadcrumbs UI tracks your history, and doesn't tell you where you're going before you get there.

Comment: To be precise, breadcrumbs don't show your history--they show where you are in the site's hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I've always interpreted it as a history trail, rather than explicitly a hierarchy.